# Access to list elements in Stata

Tags: list, foreach, stata

Imagine you have to run the following in Stata

```
tab var1 region if var1 > 4

tab var2 region if var2 > 32

tab var3 region if var3 > 7
```

and so on for many variables. Notice that the filter fed to `if` depends on the variable.

I would like to do the same by iterating over a list of variables. Something like

```
thresholdList = "4 32 7 ..." /// don't know if this works

foreach myvar of var1 var2 var3 ... {
    tab `myvar' region if `myvar' > thresholdList(`counter')
    local counter = `counter' + 1
}
```

`

Clearly, the code here above does not work in Stata. I'm trying to understand how can I define a macro including a list of values and access each element of the list explicitly, i.e.

```
thresholdList(`counter')
```

Answer (score 5):

Stata can do this. The syntax you want to use should be something like this:

```
local thresholdlist "4 32 7"
local varlist "var1 var2 var3"

local numitems = wordcount("`thresholdlist'")

forv i=1/`numitems' {
 local thisthreshold : word `i' of `thresholdlist'
 local thisvar : word `i' of `varlist'
 di "variable: `thisvar', threshold: `thisthreshold'"

  tab `thisvar' region if `thisvar' > `thisthreshold'

}
```

See: http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/lang/parallel.html

Comment: +1 It would be instructive, though, to spell out the commands unabbreviated: `forvalues`, `display`, etc.

Comment: I have learned a lot about `forvalues` and `foreach` from the following article: http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=pr0005

Answer (score 0):

A couple of other suggestions and corrections to your code -  First, I'd use -tokenize- to iterate over your list of items, second use  a local macro to store your `thresholdList', and finally use "local counter`++counter'" instead of "local counter = counter+1" to iterate your counter, so:

```
clear
set obs 200
forval n = 1/3 {
    g var`n' = ceil(runiform()*10)
    }
g region = 1


loc thresholdList  "4 32 7 " //here's your list
token `"`thresholdList'"'
**notice how tokenize stores these values:
di "`1'"
di "`2'"
**now you'll iterate i to reference the token locations:
loc i = 1
foreach myvar in var1 var2 var3 { //use 'of' not 'in'
     tab `myvar' region if `myvar' > ``i''
    loc i `++i'  //iterates `i'

}
```